# Django model query with not equal exclusion

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to create query that has a not equal parameter, but in exclusion part.

All posts suggest to exclude the parameters that should be not equal.

So what I need is :

```
Object.objects.filter(param1=p).exclude(param2=False, param3=False, param4 != q)
```

I try

```
Object.objects.filter(param1=p).exclude(param2=False, param3=False).exclude(param4=q)
```

but, as expected, doesn't work it is the same as `exclude(param2=False, param3=False, param4=q)`

So how to do it, or how to rightly chain exclude statements, so that second exclude is pointed to first exclude and not first filter.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that you want to **include** records where appropriate value **is equal**? (`filter(param1=p, param4=q)`)

Comment: No, this is not the same. If param4 is in first filter (as suggested), then even if param4 has value q and also param2=False and param3=False, this would be excluded. I need to exclude only if param4 is not q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a kind of logical question.

`Exclude (field1 != value1)` is same as `Include(field1 = value1)`

So, you can use the **`filter()`** metbod as,

```
Object.objects.filter(param1=p, param4=q).exclude(param2=False, param3=False)
```

### Or

Use [**`Q()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) object with **`~`** symbol

```
from django.db.models import Q
Object.objects.filter(param1=p).exclude(~Q(param4=q), param2=False, param3=False)
```

Comment: Hi, The first approach is not correct, because the  exclude is done after filter. For example if we would have row (p, False, False, q) in first approach this would be excluded (logic is: from whatever you found in filter exclude those with both False params) in second approach this would not be filtered (logic is: from whatever you found in filter exclude those that are not q AND have both False).